# SQLServer lock table during stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

I've got a table where I need to auto-assign an ID 99% of the time (the other 1% rules out using an identity column it seems).  So I've got a stored procedure to get next ID along the following lines:

`select @nextid = lastid+1 from last_auto_id
check next available id in the table...
update last_auto_id set lastid = @nextid`

Where the check has to check if users have manually used the IDs and find the next unused ID.

It works fine when I call it serially, returning 1, 2, 3 ...  What I need to do is provide some locking where multiple processes call this at the same time.  Ideally, I just need it to exclusively lock the last_auto_id table around this code so that a second call must wait for the first to update the table before it can run it's select.

In Postgres, I can do something like 'LOCK TABLE last_auto_id;' to explicitly lock the table.  Any ideas how to accomplish it in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You guys have between you answered my question.  I'm putting in my own reply to collate the working solution I've got into one post.  The key seems to have been the transaction approach, with locking hints on the last_auto_id table.  Setting the transaction isolation to serializable seemed to create deadlock problems.

Here's what I've got (edited to show the full code so hopefully I can get some further answers...):

```
DECLARE @Pointer AS INT

BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Check what the next ID to use should be
SELECT @NextId = LastId + 1 FROM Last_Auto_Id WITH (TABLOCKX) WHERE Name = 'CustomerNo'

-- Now check if this next ID already exists in the database
IF EXISTS (SELECT CustomerNo FROM Customer
           WHERE ISNUMERIC(CustomerNo) = 1 AND CustomerNo = @NextId)
BEGIN
  -- The next ID already exists - we need to find the next lowest free ID
  CREATE TABLE #idtbl ( IdNo int )

  -- Into temp table, grab all numeric IDs higher than the current next ID
  INSERT INTO #idtbl
  SELECT CAST(CustomerNo AS INT) FROM Customer
  WHERE ISNUMERIC(CustomerNo) = 1 AND CustomerNo >= @NextId
  ORDER BY CAST(CustomerNo AS INT)

  -- Join the table with itself, based on the right hand side of the join
  -- being equal to the ID on the left hand side + 1.  We're looking for
  -- the lowest record where the right hand side is NULL (i.e. the ID is
  -- unused)
  SELECT @Pointer = MIN( t1.IdNo ) + 1 FROM #idtbl t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #idtbl t2 ON t1.IdNo + 1 = t2.IdNo
  WHERE t2.IdNo IS NULL
END

UPDATE Last_Auto_Id SET LastId = @NextId WHERE Name = 'CustomerNo'

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SELECT @NextId
```

This takes out an exclusive table lock at the start of the transaction, which then successfully queues up any further requests until after this request has updated the table and committed it's transaction.

I've written a bit of C code to hammer it with concurrent requests from half a dozen sessions and it's working perfectly.

However, I do have one worry which is the term locking 'hints' - does anyone know if SQLServer treats this as a definite instruction or just a hint (i.e. maybe it won't always obey it??)

Answer (score 5):

Following update increments your lastid by one and assigns this value to your local variable in a single transaction.

**Edit**

thanks to Dave and Mitch for pointing out isolation level problems with the original solution.

```
UPDATE  last_auto_id WITH (READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
SET     @nextid = lastid = lastid + 1
```

Comment: If the isolation level is set to Read Uncommited, I imagine it might lead to dirty reads resolving in incorrect results. I've altered the answer to include a locking hint.

Comment: This is not a high enough isolation level.  You need to be REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE.  It also doesn't compile.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be enough isolation level? I imagine everyone uses that procedure to alter the table last_auto_id.

Comment: @asc99c, you already have a working solution but could you verify if my (final) edit works for you? I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Lieven, the problem is that I hadn't really posted the entirety of what the procedure is doing.  I edited my answering post to show the complete SQL.  Your solution sohuld be fine if I was only ever adding 1 to the ID.In the normal case I do just add 1.  But in the edge case where the resulting ID is already in use, it then does an extra bit of work to get the next unused ID.

Answer (score 2):

How is this solution? **No TABLE LOCK is required and works perfectly!!!**

```
DECLARE  @NextId INT

UPDATE   Last_Auto_Id 
SET      @NextId = LastId = LastId + 1
WHERE    Name = 'CustomerNo'

SELECT   @NextId
```

[Update statement always uses a lock to protect its update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720597/how-sql-server-handles-update-transactions).

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna consider deadlocks. This usually happens when multiple users use the stored procedure simultaneously. In order to avoid deadlock and make sure every query from the user will succeed you will need to do some handling during update failures and to do this you will need a try catch. This works on Sql Server 2005,2008 only.

```
DECLARE @Tries tinyint

SET @Tries = 1

WHILE @Tries <= 3

BEGIN

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  BEGIN TRY

-- this line updates the last_auto_id

update last_auto_id set lastid = lastid+1

   COMMIT

   BREAK
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

   SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage

   ROLLBACK

   SET @Tries = @Tries + 1

   CONTINUE

 END CATCH

END
```

Comment: This just performs a retry.  It doesn't say anything about locking.

Comment: Actually it could have been a useful solution, as I was getting deadlocks when I originally tried using transactions (when I was using SERIALIZABLE isolation level).  Not entirely sure where SQL Server thought the deadlock was, but this may have sorted it.

Comment: @Dave.. I cases like multiple user tries to access the same procedure at the same time would probably cause a deadlock especially when an important process like update or insert happens. In asc99c's case, he needs to accept the request and get the latest id from the table. I'm trying to suggest the best way to accept the same request of multiple users accessing the same table at the same time. You might wanna try to read this link to have a better understanding on what I really mean. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175791%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing this using an `identity` field in a second table.  If you make `lastid` `identity` then all you have to do is insert a row in that table and select `@scope_identity` to get your new value and you still have the concurrency safety of `identity` even though the id field in your main table is not `identity`.

Comment: The only problem is performance where the identity reaches a large range of values that have been manually used.  The code is used to generate customer IDs.  When a user imports a block of customers from another system, they can attempt to re-use their existing customer IDs if the IDs are not already used in this system.  So it may be that a block of IDs from say 10,000 to 45,000 has been loaded in from another system.  When the auto-numbering hits 10,000, it will need to jump to 45,001.  Nasty little design feature but it tends to be that way when taking over an existing system.

Comment: +1.  This is the best solution for you -- it scales much, much better than locking an entire table, and it will be more reliable in the long run.  Using a table hint can be dangerous if someone comes along and edits your procedure without testing it in a concurrent environment.

Comment: @asc99c: you can still use IDENTITY.  For those times when someone performs a data load, you can use SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourtablename ON.  If you want to re-seed the identity values in bulk loading situations, use DBCC CHECKIDENT (see books online) to re-set the identity seed value to start at the higher number.