# How SQL Server handles UPDATE transactions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions, table-locking

We have a table which is used to Generate Unique Numeric keys. These keys are then used as a PrimaryKey in other tables. Table structure is like this:

```
TableName     VARCHAR
CurrentKey    INT
```

So we have data in this table like

```
TableName   Customers
CurrentKey  400
```

So when we need next primary key for table `Customers` we get the `CurrentKey` from this table where `TableName` is `Customers`, it will give us 400 we increment (400+1) it and we update this key in the table also. So our `CurrentKey` is 401 now.

The sql we use for this purpose is:

**SQL1:**

```
DECLARE  @CurrentKey INT
UPDATE  myTable 
SET @CurrentKey = CurrentKey = CurrentKey + 1
WHERE   TableName = @TableName
```

My question is that Do we need to LOCK the table so that the keys may not duplicate if multiple users call this at the same time? i am sure that SQL Server will not allow duplicate data but i don't know HOW... Query with Table Lock:

**SQL2**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE  @CurrentKey INT
    UPDATE  myTable WITH (TABLOCKX)
    SET @CurrentKey = CurrentKey = CurrentKey + 1
    WHERE   TableName = @TableName
END TRANSACTION
```

Can someone please explain how the SQL Server handles `UPDATE` calls?

Comment: You should really leave it up to SQL Server to handle consecutive numbers, by using the `INT IDENTITY` column type. **Don't try to do this on your own!** there are soooooooooo many ways to fail ....

Comment: Dare I ask why you're trying to re-invent `IDENTITY` columns? Plus why would you keep a table of the current values centrally? Waste of time, probably wrong, and less accurate than querying the table directly.

Comment: The database is more than 12 years old and i am not allowed to change the old logics!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each SQL statement runs in a transaction, and an `update` statement always uses a lock to protect its update.  SQL Server does not allow you to read a half-modified row (with some exceptions for data that is larger than 8k.)

Your first statement should be fine.